# How do you remove yourself from San Junipero?

Tags: black-mirror

When Yorkie is convincing Kelly to choose San Junipero after passing, this is the conversation they have:

> Kelly : Who can even make sense of forever?
>
> Yorkie : However long you want then. I mean, you can remove yourself like that! (snaps fingers)

How does one remove themselves from San Junipero? (After passing and getting "uploaded" there) I dont think there is any other reference to this in the episode. How would the "minds", now uploaded to a server, communicate their decision to the real world?

Comment: Do you mean returning to the real world after a trial period, or being removed completely after being permanently uploaded (and dying)?

Comment: I think THEY meant being removed from San Junipero after dying and being permanently uploaded. So my question is about that too. (I've edited it in now) I understand how you return after/during the trial period.

Comment: Why would they need to communicate with the real world? Like you said, they're fully uploaded to the server and integrated into what is almost certainly an automated system. A simple command would allow anyone to terminate themselves / deallocate whatever memory is storing their consciousness.

Comment: Of course, what's possibly scarier is that anybody with admin privileges, or a clever hacker, could get into the system and issue that command to every instance on the server, effectively killing everyone (again) and deleting the afterlife.

Comment: A simple command that they would run how? They're just mind or consciousness. Are they supposed to think of a command? Isn't that a little risky, making permanent decisions by thought alone? And "running a command" would also constitute for communicating with the real world, don't you think - the servers maintaining all of this being very much a part of the real world.

Comment: How do you remove yourself from San Junipero? Like *that!* *[snaps fingers]*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**They don't (necessarily) have to communicate anything to the real world.**

Since the technology shown in "San Junipero" is so advanced compared to the (current) real world, speaking in terms of existing computers may or may not be useful.  However...

In the episode, people are described as being "uploaded" to a server, which would indicate that each is a file sitting in storage. This generates the confusion you indicate; files in storage can't remove themselves, and would have to be removed manually.

But there's an alternative explanation that makes it much simpler: **people in San Junipero aren't files. They're processes**.

A [processor's job](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-does-a-processor-work.html) is to pull a set of instructions (a process), run it, and send the results back to memory. If a process contains an infinite loop, the processor will keep running it forever (until it's powered off).  A "person" might be a process that contains an infinite loop, but can terminate itself by meeting certain conditions (we're never really told what it takes to remove yourself from San Junipero; maybe just wanting it badly enough will do this).  Once the process terminates, it's removed from the processor and sent to memory-- a databank of people who used to be "alive" (i.e. running), but have been terminated.

Edit: A more straight-forward option is that the process contains an instruction like `while (not doing the termination command) {run()}`

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense technology wise. The only gap that remains is the condition which would break the loop, which as you said, was never mentioned in the episode. Isn't it a beauty when programming meets fiction!